# How do i append a list to a jquery-forms-plugin before form submit?

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-forms-plugin

Im using the jquery-forms-plugin and its working great! But now i want to append an array in the beforeSubmit function.

```
questions = ['hi?','yo?','lol??'];
formData.push({name:'questions',value:questions});
```

But when i recieve this at my webserver (Using flask.py) it comes just as a plain string. like this:
hi?,yo?,lol??

Any input why it does not come as an array or list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In `formData.push({name:'questions',value:questions});` whatever you have in `questions` will encounter as string, so you found that plain string.

So you may use a string like below in `questions` and you may parse that plain CSV string in python explicitly.

```
questions = "'hi?','yo?','lol??'";
```

Again you can apply the following trick :

```
formData.push({name:'questions[0]',value:'hi?'});
formData.push({name:'questions[1]',value:'yo?'});
formData.push({name:'questions[2]',value:'lol??'});
```

So you suppose to have `questions` as list in server end.

Comment: Okay thanks! I suppose i could go with CSV format.. When i tryed your approuch to send a list i just got multipli values for each question in the server. Like questions[0] then question[1]. Not as a list.